# Is there a way to modify Kadane's Algorithm such that we know the resulting subarray?

Tags: algorithms, maximum-subarray

Kadane's Algorithm is an algorithm that solves the maximum subarray problem by clever dynamic programming. Is there a way to further modify the algorithm so that we would get to know the resulting subarray that produces the corresponding maximum sum?

PS: I don't know whether I should post this here, or Stack Overflow, or both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can.

Kadanes's algorithm keeps the value of the best subarray in a variable, let's call it `best_sum`.
Notice the invariant in the algorithm.
`best_sum` will always (after each iteration) contain the value of the maxium subarray of the prefix of the array that you already visited.
Additionally you know the best suffix sum of the current prefix, let's call it `current_sum`, which you use to update `best_sum`.

You just need to do the same thing with the position.
Introduce three more variables `current_startindex`, `best_startindex` and `best_endindex`. `current_startindex` tells you, at which position the current best suffix starts. `best_startindex` and `best_endindex` indicate the start and end of the best subarray from the visited prefix.
Keep those variables valid in each iteration. E.g.
Whenever you update `current_best`, also update `current_startindex`.
And whenever you update `best_max`, also update the `best_startindex` and `best_endindex`, so that at the end of each iteration the value is correct.

After iterating over the complete array, `best_sum` will contain the sum of values of the maximum subarray, and `best_startindex` and `best_endindex` will tell you the positions.